# Error de Sintaxis Python (ctx = dict(self.env.context) for record in self:)

Tags: python-3.x

Soy nueva en Python, tengo un error de sintaxis con el siguiente código, solo trato de dividir **qty_available** entre **weight**, considerando que **qty_available** puede ser cero.

```
ctx = dict(self.env.context)

for record in self:

    if record['product_id.qty_available'] <= 0:

        print record['x_prueba'] = 0:

    elif record['product_id.qty_available'] > 0:

        else record['x_prueba'] = record.product_id.qty_available / product_id.weight:
```

Comment: Tú pregunta es difícil de responder porque no sé exactamente que es lo que quieres hacer, y puede que la finalidad de lo que tú quieres hacer no se consiga con este código, de todas formas te respondo a la pregunta, corrigiendote la sintaxis del código, cualquier cosa me dices :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores de sintaxis:

1. **Print en la versión 3 de python va entre paréntesis**, no con espacio, y no tienes que poner los dos puntos al final de la condición
2. **Después de el "elif", al igual que del "if" tiene que ir un resultado**, no puede ir un "else". ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer si se da esa condición "elif"?
3. **El "else" tienes que indentarlo (tabularlo) como si fuera un if/elif** sin ningún tipo de condición simplemente vacío con dos puntos.

Te dejo aquí como creo que quieres hacer el script, que será más sencillo:

```
for record in self:
    if record['product_id.qty_available'] <= 0:
        record['x_prueba'] = 0
    else:
        record['x_prueba'] = record.product_id.qty_available / product_id.weight:
```

Como un número siempre tiene que ser por obligación menor/igual que 0 o mayor, con un else es suficiente.

Por último te recomiendo que escribas el código sin los espacios entre lineas, tal y como lo he escrito yo, ya que es más entendible y "pythonico".

Comment: Muchas Gracias #Rubiales Alberto, estoy poniendo en practica tus recomendaciones. Aun estoy teniendo errores con la sintaxis.

Comment: ValueError: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: "product_id.qty_available" while evaluating
u"#ctx = dict(self.env.context)\nfor record in self:\n                                       if record['product_id.qty_available'] <= 0:\n                                                                                                                                                                   record['x_prueba'] = 0\n    else:\n        record['x_prueba'] =  record.product_id.qty_available / product_id.weight"

Comment: mmm es que tú pregunta es muy abierta, necesito más información para poder ayudarte.

'Self' qué es un Dataframe?, una lista? Una lista de Dataframes?

Si editas la pregunta y pones a continuación de lo ya escrito un apartado con todo el código completo, tal vez te pueda ayudar!